# 2D Tile Based Particle Collisions

Tags: xna, collision-detection, tiles, tilemap, particles

I have a basic 2D particle system  and I'm now looking to implement collisions, however I'm not sure on what the best way to do it is. My game is tile based and runs in XNA Game Studio 4.0. I've seen the platformer sample which has the player's collisions system working like this:

```
for(int x = leftTile; x <= rightTile; x++)
{
    for(int y = topTile; y <= bottomTile; y++)
    {
        if(TileIsSolid(x, y))
        {
            //Resolve...
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is feasible to run on 300 particles at one time, and it needs it support tiny fast moving objects such as bullets from a weapon. So how do I go about implementing 2D tile based particle collisions?

Comment: Have you tried searching for this? There are a lot of resources both on this site and on search engines regarding how to implement 2D collisions including information on how to handle fast moving objects.

Comment: You want to look up CCD Collision.

Comment: Yeah I've tried searching around but just couldn't find any particle or tiny object oriented collision detection sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to perform the checks.

There are several ways of doing this. You certainly don't want to go the dumb way, that is, checking each pair of objects in the scene. No, implement something called a [quadtree](https://www.google.com/search?q=quadtree%20collision%20detection). It's a space-partitioning algorithm that greatly increases the speed and efficiency of collision detection.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple grid work as well? Quadtrees work better if most objects aren't moving.

Comment: It's tile-based! The tiles already *are* in a simple grid. You should be able to lookup just the tiles that a given object overlaps based on the world co-ordinates. Object-object collisions are a different matter and need their own broadphase, of course.

Comment: OK, then please be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve. Just particle-particle collisions? particle-object?

Comment: I want the particles to collide with the tiles. So particle-object. I will worry about particle-particle collisions later.